# HTML to Formatting Objects conversion

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

this is a sample of my XML output (which I cannot change because it's output by a CRM software over which I have no control):

```
<description><div><strong>Why</strong> is this not bold?</div> </description>
```

the `<description>` tags are proper xml tags, while `<div>` and `<strong>` are output as plain text in the pdf (see pic)
[pdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNqjR.png)

I am trying to have them rendered properly and found this article online https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/index.html but unfortunately the downloads are not available anymore. Can anyone explain to me how to apply the templates provided in the article to my XSLT file?

the XSLT for the snippet provided is currently this:

```
<fo:table margin-bottom="10mm">
            <fo:table-column column-width="100%"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                  <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="testBorderLeft">
                      <fo:block font-weight="bold">Detailed Description</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="testBorderLeft">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/hash/description"/>
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

How can incorporate for example this?

```
<xsl:template match="strong">
  <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

Coding is really not my job, but I have to do this for work, so if you could be patient and very very clear it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:value-of select="/hash/description"/>` try `<xsl: apply-templates select="/hash/description/node()"/>`. This is assuming you have templates for the elements included in the `description` element. Hard to tell when you post snippets instead of [mcve].

Comment: You will need to parse the string into nodes, with XSLT 1.0 processor this is sometimes possible with an extension function but how that works is very much specific to the processor, its API and the programming language used with or exposed.